# Communication between client and server is erratic

Tags: c++, infiniband

I modified [thegeekinthecorner](https://thegeekinthecorner.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/rdma-tutorial-pdfs/) examples to be able to continuously send data.
I am using g++4.9.2.

I tried uninstalling the oficial latest OFED from here http://downloads.openfabrics.org/OFED/

```
OFED Distribution Software Installation Menu

   1) View OFED Installation Guide
   2) Install OFED Software
   3) Show Installed Software
   4) Configure IPoIB
   5) Uninstall OFED Software

   Q) Exit

Select Option [1-5]:5

Uninstalling the previous version of OFED
Running rpm -e --allmatches libibverbs libibverbs-devel libibverbs-utils libmthca libmlx4 libcxgb3 libnes libipathverbs libibcm libibumad libibumad-devel libibmad ibacm librdmacm librdmacm-utils librdmacm-devel opensm opensm-libs dapl perftest mstflint ibutils infiniband-diags qperf infinipath-psm opensm opensm-libs libipathverbs dapl libibcm libibmad libibumad libibumad-devel libibverbs libibverbs-devel libibverbs-utils libipathverbs libmthca libmlx4 librdmacm librdmacm-devel librdmacm-utils ibacm ibutils ibutils-libs libnes infinipath-psm
Failed to uninstall the previous installation
See /tmp/OFED.22320.logs/ofed_uninstall.log
[idf@node1 OFED-1.5.4-20110726-0732]$ 
[idf@node1 OFED-1.5.4-20110726-0732]$
```

If instead I just try to install it, I get this:

```
OFED Distribution Software Installation Menu

   1) Basic (OFED modules and basic user level libraries)
   2) HPC (OFED modules and libraries, MPI and diagnostic tools)
   3) All packages (all of Basic, HPC)
   4) Customize

   Q) Exit

Select Option [1-4]:3

Please choose an implementation of MVAPICH2:

1) OFA (IB and iWARP)
2) uDAPL
Implementation [1]: 1

Enable ROMIO support [Y/n]: 

Enable shared library support [Y/n]: 

Enable Checkpoint-Restart support [y/N]: 
Kernel 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 is not supported.
For the list of Supported Platforms and Operating Systems see
/mnt/gluster/Downloads/OFED-1.5.4-20110726-0732/docs/OFED_release_notes.txt
[idf@node1 OFED-1.5.4-20110726-0732]$ 

[idf@node2 Release]$ lspci | grep -i mel
02:00.0 InfiniBand: Mellanox Technologies MT26428 [ConnectX VPI PCIe 2.0 5GT/s - IB QDR / 10GigE] (rev b0)
[idf@node2 Release]$ 


[idf@node1 Release]$ ibv_devinfo
hca_id: mlx4_0
    transport:          InfiniBand (0)
    fw_ver:             2.7.200
    node_guid:          0025:90ff:ff1a:081c
    sys_image_guid:         0025:90ff:ff1a:081f
    vendor_id:          0x02c9
    vendor_part_id:         26428
    hw_ver:             0xB0
    board_id:           SM_2092000001000
    phys_port_cnt:          1
        port:   1
            state:          PORT_ACTIVE (4)
            max_mtu:        4096 (5)
            active_mtu:     4096 (5)
            sm_lid:         1
            port_lid:       2
            port_lmc:       0x00
            link_layer:     InfiniBand

[idf@node1 Release]$ ifconfig -a

ib0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 2044
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::225:90ff:ff1a:71  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
Infiniband hardware address can be incorrect! Please read BUGS section in ifconfig(8).
        infiniband 80:00:00:48:FE:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 256  (InfiniBand)
        RX packets 5  bytes 280 (280.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 27 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Below is the client and server. When I run this programs, the clients will send messages, but the number of messages it sends is erratic, error messages are often

**Client:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <rdma/rdma_cma.h>

#define TEST_NZ(x) do { if ( (x)) die("error: " #x " failed (returned non-zero)." ); } while (0)
#define TEST_Z(x)  do { if (!(x)) die("error: " #x " failed (returned zero/null)."); } while (0)

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
const int TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 500; /* ms */

struct context
{
    struct ibv_context *ctx;
    struct ibv_pd *pd;
    struct ibv_cq *cq;
    struct ibv_comp_channel *comp_channel;

    pthread_t cq_poller_thread;
};

struct connection
{
    struct rdma_cm_id *id;
    struct ibv_qp *qp;

    struct ibv_mr *recv_mr;
    struct ibv_mr *send_mr;

    char *recv_region;
    char *send_region;

    int num_completions;
};

static pthread_t msgThread;

static void die(const char *reason);

static void build_context(struct ibv_context *verbs);
static void build_qp_attr(struct ibv_qp_init_attr *qp_attr);
static void * poll_cq(void *);
static void post_receives(struct connection *conn);
static void register_memory(struct connection *conn);

static int on_addr_resolved(struct rdma_cm_id *id);
static void on_completion(struct ibv_wc *wc);
static int on_connection(void *context);
static int on_disconnect(struct rdma_cm_id *id);
static int on_event(struct rdma_cm_event *event);
static int on_route_resolved(struct rdma_cm_id *id);

static struct context *s_ctx = NULL;

#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

bool ok_to_send_next_message = 1;
bool message_available()
{
    return 0 != ok_to_send_next_message;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct addrinfo *addr;
    struct rdma_cm_event *event = NULL;
    struct rdma_cm_id *conn= NULL;
    struct rdma_event_channel *ec = NULL;

    if (argc != 3)
        die("usage: client <server-address> <server-port>");

    TEST_NZ(getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], NULL, &addr));

    TEST_Z(ec = rdma_create_event_channel());
    TEST_NZ(rdma_create_id(ec, &conn, NULL, RDMA_PS_TCP));
    TEST_NZ(rdma_resolve_addr(conn, NULL, addr->ai_addr, TIMEOUT_IN_MS));

    freeaddrinfo(addr);

    while (0 == rdma_get_cm_event(ec, &event))
        //while (rdma_get_cm_event(ec, &event))
    {
        std::cout << "rdma_get_cm_event\n";

        struct rdma_cm_event event_copy;

        memcpy(&event_copy, event, sizeof(*event));
        rdma_ack_cm_event(event);

        if (on_event(&event_copy))
            break;
    }

    rdma_destroy_event_channel(ec);

    return 0;
}

void die(const char *reason)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", reason);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void build_context(struct ibv_context *verbs)
{
    if (s_ctx)
    {
        if (s_ctx->ctx != verbs)
            die("cannot handle events in more than one context.");

        return;
    }

    s_ctx = (struct context *)malloc(sizeof(struct context));

    s_ctx->ctx = verbs;

    TEST_Z(s_ctx->pd = ibv_alloc_pd(s_ctx->ctx));
    TEST_Z(s_ctx->comp_channel = ibv_create_comp_channel(s_ctx->ctx));
    TEST_Z(s_ctx->cq = ibv_create_cq(s_ctx->ctx, 100, NULL, s_ctx->comp_channel, 0)); /* cqe=10 is arbitrary */
    TEST_NZ(ibv_req_notify_cq(s_ctx->cq, 0));

    TEST_NZ(pthread_create(&s_ctx->cq_poller_thread, NULL, poll_cq, NULL));
}

void *SendMessages(void *context)
{
    static int loopcount = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.wait(lck, message_available);
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(50));

        ok_to_send_next_message = 0;

        struct connection *conn = (struct connection *)context;
        struct ibv_send_wr wr, *bad_wr = NULL;
        struct ibv_sge sge;

        std::cout << "looping send..." << loopcount << '\n' << std::flush;

        memset(&wr, 0, sizeof(wr));

        wr.wr_id = (uintptr_t)conn;
        wr.opcode = IBV_WR_SEND;
        wr.sg_list = &sge;
        wr.num_sge = 1;
        wr.send_flags = IBV_SEND_SIGNALED;

        sge.addr = (uintptr_t)conn->send_region;
        sge.length = BUFFER_SIZE;
        sge.lkey = conn->send_mr->lkey;

        snprintf(conn->send_region, BUFFER_SIZE, "message from active/client side with count %d", loopcount++);
        TEST_NZ(ibv_post_send(conn->qp, &wr, &bad_wr));
    }
}

void build_qp_attr(struct ibv_qp_init_attr *qp_attr)
{
    std::cout << "build_qp_attr\n";

    memset(qp_attr, 0, sizeof(*qp_attr));

    qp_attr->send_cq = s_ctx->cq;
    qp_attr->recv_cq = s_ctx->cq;
    qp_attr->qp_type = IBV_QPT_RC;

    qp_attr->cap.max_send_wr = 100;
    qp_attr->cap.max_recv_wr = 100;
    qp_attr->cap.max_send_sge = 1;
    qp_attr->cap.max_recv_sge = 1;
}

void * poll_cq(void *ctx)
{
    struct ibv_cq *cq;
    struct ibv_wc wc;

    while (1)
    {
        TEST_NZ(ibv_get_cq_event(s_ctx->comp_channel, &cq, &ctx));
        ibv_ack_cq_events(cq, 1);
        TEST_NZ(ibv_req_notify_cq(cq, 0));

        int ne;
        struct ibv_wc wc;

        do
        {
            std::cout << "polling\n";
            ne = ibv_poll_cq(cq, 1, &wc);
        }
        while(ne == 0);

        on_completion(&wc);

        //if (wc.opcode == IBV_WC_SEND)
        if (wc.status == IBV_WC_SUCCESS)
        {
            {
                ok_to_send_next_message = 1;
                //while (message_available()) std::this_thread::yield();
                //std::cout << "past yield\n";
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
                cv.notify_one();
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void post_receives(struct connection *conn)
{
    std::cout << "post_receives\n";

    struct ibv_recv_wr wr, *bad_wr = NULL;
    struct ibv_sge sge;

    wr.wr_id = (uintptr_t)conn;
    wr.next = NULL;
    wr.sg_list = &sge;
    wr.num_sge = 1;

    sge.addr = (uintptr_t)conn->recv_region;
    sge.length = BUFFER_SIZE;
    sge.lkey = conn->recv_mr->lkey;

    TEST_NZ(ibv_post_recv(conn->qp, &wr, &bad_wr));
}

void register_memory(struct connection *conn)
{
    std::cout << "register_memory\n";

    conn->send_region = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    conn->recv_region = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    TEST_Z(conn->send_mr = ibv_reg_mr(
                               s_ctx->pd,
                               conn->send_region,
                               BUFFER_SIZE,
                               IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE | IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE));

    TEST_Z(conn->recv_mr = ibv_reg_mr(
                               s_ctx->pd,
                               conn->recv_region,
                               BUFFER_SIZE,
                               IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE | IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE));
}

int on_addr_resolved(struct rdma_cm_id *id)
{
    std::cout << "on_addr_resolved\n";

    struct ibv_qp_init_attr qp_attr;
    struct connection *conn;

    build_context(id->verbs);
    build_qp_attr(&qp_attr);

    TEST_NZ(rdma_create_qp(id, s_ctx->pd, &qp_attr));

    id->context = conn = (struct connection *)malloc(sizeof(struct connection));

    conn->id = id;
    conn->qp = id->qp;
    conn->num_completions = 0;

    register_memory(conn);
    post_receives(conn);

    TEST_NZ(rdma_resolve_route(id, TIMEOUT_IN_MS));

    return 0;
}

void on_completion(struct ibv_wc *wc)
{
    std::cout << "on_completion\n";

    struct connection *conn = (struct connection *)(uintptr_t)wc->wr_id;

    if (wc->status != IBV_WC_SUCCESS)
    {
        //die("\ton_completion: status is not IBV_WC_SUCCESS.");
        printf("\ton_completion: status is not IBV_WC_SUCCESS.");
        printf("\t it is %d ", wc->status);
    }

    printf("\n");

    if (wc->opcode & IBV_WC_RECV)
        printf("\treceived message: %s\n", conn->recv_region);
    else if (wc->opcode == IBV_WC_SEND)
        printf("\tsend completed successfully.\n");
    else
        die("\ton_completion: completion isn't a send or a receive.");

    if (5 == ++conn->num_completions)
        rdma_disconnect(conn->id);
}

int on_connection(void *context)
{
    std::cout << "on_connection\n";

    TEST_NZ(pthread_create(&msgThread, NULL, SendMessages, context));

    return 0;
}

int on_disconnect(struct rdma_cm_id *id)
{
    struct connection *conn = (struct connection *)id->context;

    printf("disconnected.\n");

    rdma_destroy_qp(id);

    ibv_dereg_mr(conn->send_mr);
    ibv_dereg_mr(conn->recv_mr);

    free(conn->send_region);
    free(conn->recv_region);

    free(conn);

    rdma_destroy_id(id);

    return 1; /* exit event loop */
}

int on_route_resolved(struct rdma_cm_id *id)
{
    struct rdma_conn_param cm_params;

    printf("route resolved.\n");

    memset(&cm_params, 0, sizeof(cm_params));
    TEST_NZ(rdma_connect(id, &cm_params));

    return 0;
}

int on_event(struct rdma_cm_event *event)
{
    int r = 0;

    if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_ADDR_RESOLVED)
        r = on_addr_resolved(event->id);
    else if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_ROUTE_RESOLVED)
        r = on_route_resolved(event->id);
    else if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_ESTABLISHED)
        r = on_connection(event->id->context);
    else if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_DISCONNECTED)
        r = on_disconnect(event->id);
    else
        die("on_event: unknown event.");

    return r;
}
```

**Server:**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <rdma/rdma_cma.h>

#define TEST_NZ(x) do { if ( (x)) die("error: " #x " failed (returned non-zero)." ); } while (0)
#define TEST_Z(x)  do { if (!(x)) die("error: " #x " failed (returned zero/null)."); } while (0)

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

struct context
{
    struct ibv_context *ctx;
    struct ibv_pd *pd;
    struct ibv_cq *cq;
    struct ibv_comp_channel *comp_channel;

    pthread_t cq_poller_thread;
};

struct connection
{
    struct ibv_qp *qp;

    struct ibv_mr *recv_mr;
    struct ibv_mr *send_mr;

    char *recv_region;
    char *send_region;
};

static void die(const char *reason);

static void build_context(struct ibv_context *verbs);
static void build_qp_attr(struct ibv_qp_init_attr *qp_attr);
static void * poll_cq(void *);
static void post_receives(struct connection *conn);
static void register_memory(struct connection *conn);

static void on_completion(struct ibv_wc *wc);
static int on_connect_request(struct rdma_cm_id *id);
static int on_connection(void *context);
static int on_disconnect(struct rdma_cm_id *id);
static int on_event(struct rdma_cm_event *event);

static struct context *s_ctx = NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
    struct rdma_cm_event *event = NULL;
    struct rdma_cm_id *listener = NULL;
    struct rdma_event_channel *ec = NULL;
    uint16_t port = 0;

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;

    TEST_Z(ec = rdma_create_event_channel());
    TEST_NZ(rdma_create_id(ec, &listener, NULL, RDMA_PS_TCP));
    TEST_NZ(rdma_bind_addr(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr));
    TEST_NZ(rdma_listen(listener, 100)); /* backlog=10 is arbitrary */

    //printf("[ %"PRIu32" ]\n", *addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr32);

    port = ntohs(rdma_get_src_port(listener));

    printf("listening on port %d.\n", port);

    while (rdma_get_cm_event(ec, &event) == 0)
    {
        struct rdma_cm_event event_copy;

        memcpy(&event_copy, event, sizeof(*event));
        rdma_ack_cm_event(event);

        if (on_event(&event_copy))
            break;
    }

    rdma_destroy_id(listener);
    rdma_destroy_event_channel(ec);

    return 0;
}

void die(const char *reason)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", reason);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void build_context(struct ibv_context *verbs)
{
    if (s_ctx)
    {
        if (s_ctx->ctx != verbs)
            die("cannot handle events in more than one context.");

        return;
    }

    s_ctx = (struct context *)malloc(sizeof(struct context));

    s_ctx->ctx = verbs;

    TEST_Z(s_ctx->pd = ibv_alloc_pd(s_ctx->ctx));
    TEST_Z(s_ctx->comp_channel = ibv_create_comp_channel(s_ctx->ctx));
    TEST_Z(s_ctx->cq = ibv_create_cq(s_ctx->ctx, 100, NULL, s_ctx->comp_channel, 0)); /* cqe=10 is arbitrary */
    TEST_NZ(ibv_req_notify_cq(s_ctx->cq, 0));

    TEST_NZ(pthread_create(&s_ctx->cq_poller_thread, NULL, poll_cq, NULL));
}

void build_qp_attr(struct ibv_qp_init_attr *qp_attr)
{
    memset(qp_attr, 0, sizeof(*qp_attr));

    qp_attr->send_cq = s_ctx->cq;
    qp_attr->recv_cq = s_ctx->cq;
    qp_attr->qp_type = IBV_QPT_RC;

    qp_attr->cap.max_send_wr = 100;
    qp_attr->cap.max_recv_wr = 100;
    qp_attr->cap.max_send_sge = 1;
    qp_attr->cap.max_recv_sge = 1;
}

void * poll_cq(void *ctx)
{
    struct ibv_cq *cq;
    struct ibv_wc wc;

    while (1)
    {
        TEST_NZ(ibv_get_cq_event(s_ctx->comp_channel, &cq, &ctx));
        ibv_ack_cq_events(cq, 1);
        TEST_NZ(ibv_req_notify_cq(cq, 0));

        while (ibv_poll_cq(cq, 1, &wc))
        {
            std::cout << "polling\n";
            on_completion(&wc);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void post_receives(struct connection *conn)
{
    std::cout << "post_receives\n";

    struct ibv_recv_wr wr, *bad_wr = NULL;
    struct ibv_sge sge;

    wr.wr_id = (uintptr_t)conn;
    wr.next = NULL;
    wr.sg_list = &sge;
    wr.num_sge = 1;

    sge.addr = (uintptr_t)conn->recv_region;
    sge.length = BUFFER_SIZE;
    sge.lkey = conn->recv_mr->lkey;

    TEST_NZ(ibv_post_recv(conn->qp, &wr, &bad_wr));
}

void register_memory(struct connection *conn)
{
    conn->send_region = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    conn->recv_region = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    TEST_Z(conn->send_mr = ibv_reg_mr(
                               s_ctx->pd,
                               conn->send_region,
                               BUFFER_SIZE,
                               IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE | IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE));

    TEST_Z(conn->recv_mr = ibv_reg_mr(
                               s_ctx->pd,
                               conn->recv_region,
                               BUFFER_SIZE,
                               IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE | IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE));
}

void on_completion(struct ibv_wc *wc)
{
    if (wc->status != IBV_WC_SUCCESS)
        die("on_completion: status is not IBV_WC_SUCCESS.");

    if (wc->opcode & IBV_WC_RECV)
    {
        struct connection *conn = (struct connection *)(uintptr_t)wc->wr_id;
        post_receives(conn);
        printf("received message: %s\n", conn->recv_region);
    }
    else if (wc->opcode == IBV_WC_SEND)
    {
        printf("send completed successfully.\n");
    }
}

int on_connect_request(struct rdma_cm_id *id)
{
    struct ibv_qp_init_attr qp_attr;
    struct rdma_conn_param cm_params;
    struct connection *conn;

    printf("received connection request.\n");

    build_context(id->verbs);
    build_qp_attr(&qp_attr);

    TEST_NZ(rdma_create_qp(id, s_ctx->pd, &qp_attr));

    id->context = conn = (struct connection *)malloc(sizeof(struct connection));
    conn->qp = id->qp;

    register_memory(conn);
    post_receives(conn);

    memset(&cm_params, 0, sizeof(cm_params));
    TEST_NZ(rdma_accept(id, &cm_params));

    return 0;
}

int on_connection(void *context)
{
    struct connection *conn = (struct connection *)context;
    struct ibv_send_wr wr, *bad_wr = NULL;
    struct ibv_sge sge;

    snprintf(conn->send_region, BUFFER_SIZE, "message from passive/server side with pid %d", getpid());

    printf("connected. posting send...\n");

    memset(&wr, 0, sizeof(wr));

    wr.opcode = IBV_WR_SEND;
    wr.sg_list = &sge;
    wr.num_sge = 1;
    wr.send_flags = IBV_SEND_SIGNALED;

    sge.addr = (uintptr_t)conn->send_region;
    sge.length = BUFFER_SIZE;
    sge.lkey = conn->send_mr->lkey;

    TEST_NZ(ibv_post_send(conn->qp, &wr, &bad_wr));

    return 0;
}

int on_disconnect(struct rdma_cm_id *id)
{
    struct connection *conn = (struct connection *)id->context;

    printf("peer disconnected.\n");

    rdma_destroy_qp(id);

    ibv_dereg_mr(conn->send_mr);
    ibv_dereg_mr(conn->recv_mr);

    free(conn->send_region);
    free(conn->recv_region);

    free(conn);

    rdma_destroy_id(id);

    return 0;
}

int on_event(struct rdma_cm_event *event)
{
    std::cout << "on_event\n";

    int r = 0;

    if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_CONNECT_REQUEST)
        r = on_connect_request(event->id);
    else if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_ESTABLISHED)
        r = on_connection(event->id->context);
    else if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_DISCONNECTED)
        r = on_disconnect(event->id);
    else
        die("on_event: unknown event.");

    return r;
}
```

Here are a couple of runs. Totally random the number of message sent:

```
[idf@node1 Release]$ ./TGKITCClient 192.168.0.1 47819
rdma_get_cm_event
on_addr_resolved
build_qp_attr
register_memory
post_receives
rdma_get_cm_event
route resolved.
rdma_get_cm_event
on_connection
looping send...0
polling
on_completion
    received message: message from passive/server side with pid 4188

polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...1
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

^C
[idf@node1 Release]$
```

And then

```
[idf@node1 Release]$ ./TGKITCClient 192.168.0.1 55148
rdma_get_cm_event
on_addr_resolved
build_qp_attr
register_memory
post_receives
rdma_get_cm_event
route resolved.
rdma_get_cm_event
on_connection
looping send...0
polling
on_completion
    received message: message from passive/server side with pid 4279

polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...1
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...2
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...3
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...4
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...5
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...6
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...7
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

looping send...8
rdma_get_cm_event
disconnected.
polling
on_completion
    send completed successfully.

    on_completion: status is not IBV_WC_SUCCESS.     it is 5 [idf@node1 Release]$
```

Here is the server side:

```
on_event
peer disconnected.
on_event
received connection request.
post_receives
on_event
connected. posting send...
polling
send completed successfully.
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 0
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 1
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 2
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 3
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 4
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 5
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 6
polling
post_receives
received message: message from active/client side with count 7
on_event
peer disconnected.
```

Comment: What's *thegeekinthecorner?* If it's important to the question, provide an explanation or link.

Comment: thegeekinthecorner is now a link in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the most recent drivers and firmware on the cards are installed.  Beyond that, using the RDMA packages included with most OS distributions when trying to run IB is a dangerous game to play.

It is strongly recommended that for applications like these the Open Fabrics Enterprise Distribution should be used to provide openib, opensm and a variety of other useful infiniband related packages for analysis diagnostics and tuning of a network.  The official OFED packages can be found on the [OpenFabrics website](http://downloads.openfabrics.org/OFED/).

Based on the question it looks like IPoIB is being used but the specific configuration is not mentioned.  IPoIB is not necessarily the best way to take advantages of the hardware resources available in the IB cards.

In addition to those considerations making sure that the subnetmanager is setup and configured correctly.  Some switches have built-in subnet managers that can be access and configured through a management interface, in other cases it might make more sense to run and configure the subnet manager on one of the nodes that you are using.  OpenSM is a common subnet manager that is included with OFED distributions and there are many online guides available for setting up and configuring a subnet manager based on the type of network being setup.

OFED also includes a variety of IB testing and profiling tools.  `ibdiagnet` is a [useful tool for debugging IB network issues](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ibdiagnet).  And there are many guides available online that show different ways to make use of the tool as well as the other tools included in OFED.

Depending on the type of IB switch used there may additionally be some network management and diagnostic tools that would allow for further analysis of the network.  The configuration of IB hardware and the low-level software that manages it is sometimes more critical to overall performance than the actual code being run.  But with that being said recompiling and linking to relevant libraries from the correct version of OFED might be advisable if significant software of hardware configuration changes are made.

Comment: Hi Matt. I added the output of ifconfig -a to post. As I stated here http://serverfault.com/questions/692643/infiniband-verifying-that-rdma-is-working all the tests work brilliantly. I am not using a switch. The two nodes are connected through a cable and the opensm is running on one of the nodes. Seems to be fine.

Comment: Do you know what the link is to update the firmware on this particular card?

Comment: I downloaded the latest OFED. It seems to be a bunch .rpms. I am using CentOS 7. I used the old fashioned yum install for what I have now. The README to the OFED says it will remove all previous installs. Do you know if that includes things I installed through yum?

Comment: I believe that you should be able to download the firmware from this page at [Mellanox](http://www.mellanox.com/page/firmware_table_ConnectXIB) if you search for the MT26428 you should be able to find the appropriate versions.  `mstflint` is the Mellanox specific firmware updating tool and these are the [Mellanox Firmware Update Instructions](http://www.mellanox.com/page/firmware_HCA_FW_update).

Comment: It would be best to use it `install.pl` script included with the OFED distribution to install OFED.  Using this script will take you through a guided process that ensures the correct packages are installed and loaded and will even allow you to configure some of the installed components during the installation process.

Comment: I couldn't find my revision o the Mellanox site. I am trying SuperMicro to see if I can see my exact card there. They also appear to have a useful document on installation ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/Firmware/InfiniBand/How%20to%20Flash%20the%20IB%20firmware%20&%20Check%20FW%20Rev%20&%20Status-03.06.2015.pdf

Comment: This is also a useful document http://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/user_manuals/ConnectX%202_VPI_UserManual.pdf

Comment: I  remember now why  i avoid the OFED. See original post. The thing doesn't work.

Comment: I can only test on IB hardware more recent and is setup and configured through OFED, so I am not certain how valid the results will be.  I have extensive experience using Mellanox equipment in the past but unfortunately no longer have direct access to the hardware needed to recreate the environment you are running on.

Comment: If you can open create a chat I can join and try to help in real(it) time

Comment: As a first step, can you try to see if it works on the hardware you have. I am curious.

Comment: I will post updates when it has run (have to wait in the scheduler queue and use lowest priority partition of the queue for this sort of thing since it is not official work, sorry for the delay)

Comment: you will need to compile with LDFLAGS= -lrdmacm -libverbs -pthread  Not clear if you need -lrt. Also, I have notice strangeness if  use CC=g++ instead of CC=gcc Obviously the programs I posted are c++, but the original TGITC are in c.

Comment: The whole purpose is to be able to send messages continously. TGITC example just sends one message.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about running this through a resource manager and/or scheduler?  In the past I had direct access to the nodes I would test on but I need to go through a scheduler and I do not have a lot of experience writing batch scripts for this sort of RDMA program in that environment.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.